# Drawing a line with an exact grade (slope)

Tags: qgis

I have a map with 5ft contour lines (screenshot below), and I am trying to draw a line to represent the shortest possible road between the purple rectangle ( a future garage) and the dashed line in the bottom left corner that will have a grade not exceeding 16%. So each segment of the line needs to be 31.25ft between vertices that intersect with each contour line.

I can closely approximate this with the measure tool, but I cannot convert it to a line.  And when I try to add a line, the measure tool disappears.

I've also tried the advanced digitizing tools, but am wondering if there is a more elegant solution?

[image: screenshot of road placement]

Comment: Interesting problem. What about tracing a line from start to finish, and wherever it is too steep, have it zig zag just the amount needed to meet the max grade requirement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a DEM for this to work. If you dont have one, you can probably find one open source or convert your contour lines to one.

It will calculate least cost path, avoiding steep slopes since we have set their cost values very high.

This is the workflow:
[image]

1. Calculate a slope raster from the DEM.
2. Reclassify this so slope values above 16 % get a very high value. The slopes are in degrees so you need to find our what degree 16 % correspond to. In my test I use:
   [image]
3. r.cost:
   [image]
4. r.drain:
   [image]

Result, the shortest path avoiding the red areas:

[image]